# android ble write Characteristic successfully but onWriteCharacteristic cannot be triggered

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using sample code of Bluetooth low energy and I have made some minor changes in it in order to write characteristics value. Here below is my code that I am using for writing characteristic value and it seems that write operation and setValue operation has been successfully but onWriteCharacterisctic() cannot be triggered .

```
public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }

    BluetoothGattService service = characteristic.getService();
    if (service == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "service was not found!");
        return;
    }

    if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(THERMOMETER_CONFIG_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
        byte[] value = { 0x55, 0x00 };
        characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16);

        if (characteristic.setValue(value)) {
            Log.e(TAG,"the setValue operation has been completed"+ DataConvert.bytesToHexString(characteristic.getValue()));
        }

        if (mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "the write operation has been completed");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "the write operation has not been completed");
        }
    }

    if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(THERMOMETER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
        /* 获取该Characteristic的Descriptor，并写入notify以开启通知 */
        List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> descriptors = characteristic
                .getDescriptors();
        BluetoothGattDescriptor mDescriptor = descriptors.get(0);
        mDescriptor
                .setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        Log.i(TAG, "Descriptor's UUID :" + mDescriptor.getUuid());
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(mDescriptor);
    }

}
```

Already I have consumed a lot of time to solve the issue but so far my effort bring no fruit.

Answer (score 0):

`setWriteType()` is the wrong place to use `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16`. Instead try the `BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue()` overload that accepts a `formatType` parameter. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#setValue(int, int, int) for more info.

I don't think you should have to explicitly call `setWriteType()` in most cases.